# python bash command: how to escape single quote?

Tags: python, bash, shell

I'm trying to execute a shell command through python. The command is like the following one:

```
su -c "lftp -c 'open -u user,password ftp://127.0.0.1; get ivan\'s\ filename.pdf' " someuser
```

So, when I try to do it in python:

```
command = "su -c \"lftp -c 'open -u user,password ftp://127.0.0.1; get ivan\'s\ filename.pdf' \" someuser"
os.system(command)
```

Or:

```
command = subprocess.Popen(["su", "-c", "lftp -c 'open -u user,password ftp://127.0.0.1; get ivan\'s\ filename.pdf'", "someuser"])
```

I get the following error:

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Referred to: ivan\'s single quote.

I know there are a lot of single/double quotes in that but how can I escape this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: THIS WORKED FOR ME:**

```
subprocess.call(["su","-c",r"""lftp -c "open -u user,password ftp://127.0.0.1; get ivan\'s\ filename.pdf" """, "someuser"])
```

Thank you all very much!

Comment: Use [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) instead and pass your individual arguments as a list without quoting anything - Python will do the escapes correct for your shell for you.

Comment: You probably want to use `curl` instead of `lftp`... You can do that via pycURL or calling the command...

Comment: I tried to do it with: subprocess.Popen(["su", "-c", "open -u user,password ftp://127.0.0.1; get ivan\'s\ filename.pdf", "someuser"]) and still have this error.

Comment: @zwer: The problem is the `su -c` which results in an unavoidable layer of shell escape processing by the shell started by `su`

Comment: Why is the `su` used? Is the script run as a normal user or root? Getting the file as the current user and then moving it and changing ownership might be much more elegant...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you printed your test string you would notice that it results in the following:

```
su -c "lftp -c 'open -u user,password ftp://127.0.0.1; get ivan's\ filename.pdf' " someuser
```

The problem is that you need to escape the slash that you use to escape the single quote in order to keep Python from eating it.

```
command = "su -c \"lftp -c 'open -u user,password ftp://127.0.0.1; get ivan\\'s\\ filename.pdf' \" someuser"
```

will get the backslash across, you will then get an error from lftp instead...

This works:

```
command = "su -c \"lftp -c \\\"open -u user,password ftp://127.0.0.1; get ivan\\'s\\ filename.pdf\\\" \" someuser"
```

(It uses (escaped) double quotes instead, to ensure that the shell started by su still interprets the escape sequences)

(`os.system(a)` effectively does `subprocess.call(["sh","-c",a])`, which means that `sh` sees `su -c "lftp -c 'open -u user,password ftp://127.0.0.1; get ivan's\ filename.pdf' " someuser` (for the original one). It does escape sequence processing on this and sees an unclosed single quote (it is initially closed by `ivan'`), resulting in your error). Once that is fixed, `sh` calls su, which in turn starts up another instance of `sh` doing more escape processing, resulting in the error from lftp (since `sh` doesn't handle escape sequences in the single quotes)

`subprocess.call()` or `curl` are better ways to implement this - `curl` will need much less escaping, you can use `curl "ftp://user:password@127.0.0.1/ivan's filename.pdf" on the command line, some more escaping is needed for going via`su -c`and for python.`sudo`instead of`su` also results in less escaping being needed....

If you want to use `subprocess.call()` (which removes one layer of shell), you can use

```
subprocess.call(["su","-c","lftp -c \\\"open -u user,password ftp://127.0.0.1; get ivan\\'s\\ filename.pdf\\\"", "someuser"])
```

(The problem is that python deals with one level of escaping, and the `sh -c` invoked from `su` with the next layer... This results in quite an ugly command...) (different quotes might slightly reduce that...)

Using `r""` can get rid of the python level escape processing: (needing only the shell level escapes) (Using triple quotes to allow quotes in the string)

```
subprocess.call(["su","-c",r"""lftp -c \"open -u user,password ftp://127.0.0.1; get ivan\'s\ filename.pdf\"""", "someuser"])
```

Adding a space allows for stripping the shell escapes, since `lftp` doesn't seem to need the filename escaped for the spaces and single quote.

```
subprocess.call(["su","-c",r"""lftp -c "open -u user,password ftp://127.0.0.1; get ivan's filename.pdf" """, "someuser"])
```

This results in the eventual `lftp` ARGV being

```
["lftp","-c","open -u user,password ftp://127.0.0.1; get ivan's filename.pdf"]
```

For curl instead (it still ends up bad due to the `su` being involved):

```
subprocess.call(["su","-c",r"""curl "ftp://user:password@127.0.0.1/ivan's filename.pdf" """, "someuser"])
```

Comment: Thank you! r"" worked for me this way:

`subprocess.call(["su","-c",r"""lftp -c "open -u user,password ftp://127.0.0.1; get ivan\'s\ filename.pdf" """, "someuser"])`

Answer (score 1):

Using subprocess.call() is the best and more secure way to perform this task.

Here's an example from the [documentation page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"]) # As you can see we have here the command and a parameter
```

About the error I think it is something related to the spaces and the ' charachter.

Try using [string literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) (pay attention to the r before the string, also be sure that the command is 100% matching the one you use in BASH):

```
r"My ' complex & string"
```

So, in your case:

```
command = subprocess.Popen(["su", "-c", r"lftp -c 'open -u user,password ftp://127.0.0.1; get ivan's filename.pdf'", "someuser"])
```

Comment: The problem is in the third command, I have a lftp -c with another command and the single quote inside it.

Comment: I've added a final comment about that @idiaz01 (string literals and using r"")

Comment: The problem is that su starts up another shell that does another layer of escape processing... You are also missing the `lftp`...

Comment: Thanks, @GertvandenBerg I've now fixed the command.
I didn't think about that, let me test a bit...

Comment: @idiaz01Can you please report is using r"" returns you the same error?

Comment: Are we forced to use su? 
Is it possible to enable the script user to issue this command instead of using root?
That would also be the best choice, security-wise.

Comment: @Pitto: `sudo` might be able to avoid the extra layer of escaping as well, since it allows a command and parameters instead... (Its configuration is more complicated though...) (Other options include using SSH to go to the user with the command in the `authorized_keys` file allowing the key used by the script to run it automatically...)

Comment: Agreed, @GertvandenBerg.
This part of the issue becomes more OS related than programming related, imho.

Comment: Still same error with this alternative. About the su, I'm forced to use it, that's why I'm stuck with this issue.